# Using IRelationshipClass

Tags: web-mapping, relationship-class, arcgis-web-adf, arcfm, relates

I have three feature classes [CircuitSource(**A**),CircuitBreaker(**B**),Sub-Station(**C**)]. In the Geodatabase A and B has a **1:1** relationship based on a primary field namely 'FEEDERID'. C and B has a **1:many** relationship based on a field namely 'STATIONID'. I have created a new feature in A(pFeatA) and related this feature to an existing feature(pFeatB) in B feature class so that the value of 'FEEDERID' in pFeatA gets populated in pFeatB. I used the following code.

**IRelationshipClass relClass = null;**

**relClass.CreateRelationship(pFeatA as IObject, pFeatB as IObject);**

But the value of 'FEEDERID' in pFeatA is getting populated in all features in B feature class which has 'FEEDERID' = null and the similar value of 'STATIONID' as that of pFeatB.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a relationship when you've mentioned that it already exists.

If you want to get related objects there are specific methods for it, like *IRelationshipClass.GetObjectsRelatedToObject* & *IRelationshipClass.GetObjectsRelatedToObjectSet*